# Windows Application has stopped working

Tags: c#, crash, windows

I have a C# windows application installed on the client machine. It was running fine, all of a sudden application crashed and when I checked exceptions, I got the following details:

> Description: Stopped working

```
<ProblemSignatures>
<EventType>CLR20r3</EventType>
<Parameter0>myapp.exe</parameter0>
<Parameter1>2.0.13</parameter0>
<Parameter2>529dadac</parameter0>
<Parameter3>mscorlib</parameter0>
<Parameter4>2.0.0.</parameter0>
<Parameter5>5174ddfb</parameter0>
<Parameter6>c43</parameter0>
<Parameter7>59</parameter0>
<Parameter8>System.FormatException</parameter0>
```

Please give valuable suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to analyse WERInternalMetadata.xml file generated by Windows Crash Reporter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218649/how-to-analyse-werinternalmetadata-xml-file-generated-by-windows-crash-reporter)

Comment: As included in your post the crash was caused by a FormatException. In most cases the reason is a wrong formated string.Format usage.

Comment: You are converting some null value in your code, find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you are getting is :- [`System.FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Here is a brief description about it:-

> FormatException is thrown when the format of an argument in a method invocation does not match the format of the corresponding formal parameter type. For example, if a method specifies a String parameter consisting of two digits with an embedded period, passing a corresponding string argument containing only two digits to that method would cause FormatException to be thrown.
>   FormatException uses the HRESULT COR_E_FORMAT, which has the value 0x80131537.

If you have a WinForm application, try doing it in you "Program.cs" file:-(default name of the file generated by viusual studio)

```
  try
  {
      Application.Run(new Form()) ; 
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
     Log(ex) ; 
  }

  void Log(Exception ex)
  {
      string stackTrace = ex.StackTrace ; 
      File.WriteAllText(youFilePathHere, stackTrace) ; // path of file where stack trace will be stored.
  }
```

By analyzing the stack-trace it will be easy for you to know a lot about the "Run time exception" you are experiencing in your application.(exact line no, method name etc).
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to analyse from this.

But,
This exception will be thrown when you convert a `null` value to a meaningful value.

By using `Convert` function you might have tried to convert null value to other.

You will have to check for null value in your code and then `assign it to 0` or any other value as convinience.