# Windows Application Startup Error Exception code: 0xe0434352

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

I Was Start Windows Application Then application Not Start.

Error Exception code: 
0xe0434352 I was find Following Error from EventViewer.

> Application_develop in Visual studio 2010,Startup error

```
      Application: POSBarcode.exe
            Framework Version: v4.0.30319
            Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
            Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
               at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
               at System.Configuration.XmlUtil..ctor(System.IO.Stream, System.String, Boolean, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()

            Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
               at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)

            Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)
               at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)
               at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(System.String, System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord)
               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
               at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(System.String, Boolean)
               at System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(System.Configuration.SettingsContext, System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyCollection)
               at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(System.Configuration.SettingsProvider)
               at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(System.String)
               at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(System.String)
               at POSBarcode.Properties.Settings.get_MotherBoardID()
               at POSBarcode.Global..cctor()

            Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
               at POSBarcode.Global..ctor()
               at POSBarcode.Login..ctor()
               at POSBarcode.Program.Main()
```

Comment: I have updated my answer a little bit. Incidentally I did not downvote your question. Perhaps you can update it a little bit with relevant information such as: what type of software is this? Do you have the source? (I am not sure looking at your question). Does this application connect to hardware devices? Etc... What type of machine are you running on? (it could be virtual, embedded or regular, or whatever else).

Answer (score 3):

Not my usual task to handle, but some sort of missing dependency or misconfiguration I would assume. This is a rehash of previous answers.

***Here is a somewhat broader-scope check-list of things to try than the below list: [EXE file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651252/exe-file-is-not-working/48654444#48654444)*** (recommended skim). Maybe try the questions below first though.

Another list:
**[Desktop applicaton not opening after installation in client system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)**

---

### Crash on Launch

> This is just a messy list intended to spark debugging ideas. Please
> improve inline if you find inaccuracies.
>
> Many things could make an application crash on launch. I doubt all the
> issues listed would cause crashes, but rather error messages. Also:
> **several of the points overlap quite a bit**.

- ***Dependency issues***: missing files & runtimes - and registrations (and maybe drivers?). Assembly binding issues (GAC, manifest).
- ***Configuration issues***: erroneous paths or URLs specified in config files  (often from developer machine). Or even a wrong license file or decryption key (see other bullet points - lots of overlaps).
- ***Encoding issues***: just to mention potential problems such as ANSI / Unicode, encryption / decryption, compression / decompression. Illegal characters in path names?
- ***Licensing issues***: invalid license or no connection to licensing server. Essentially a configuration issue, but listing it as its own issue. Could also be network related.
- ***Hardware / Driver issues***: I have seen applications crash if they can't connect to hardware (driver issues). Is that a bar-code reader application? Does it need a connected device? Maybe the driver is old, or worse: experimental. (Your exe is called `POSBarcode.exe` indicating communication with a hardware device?).
- ***Platform & Bitness issues***: mixing x86, x64 files for example. Application can't run on virtual machines? Application can only run on embedded devices? I am on shaky ground here. Just listing everything that comes to mind. Expansive list, not conclusive.
- ***Permission issues***: some sort of permission denied.

  - **licensing** issues can look and act like permission denied (no proper warning).
  - lacking **NTFS rights** (files, folders, shares, registry).
  - lacking [**NT privileges**](https://ss64.com/nt/ntrights.html).
  - problems with **authentication** & **authorization** for **database connections**.
  - blocking **security software** (anti virus, firewalls).
  - missing **AD group membership** & **group policy interference**.
  - [Code Access Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security) issues? (Shouldn't crash, should it? I know CAS has been changed a lot, I am not up to speed).
- Don't know whether to list **networking issues** (no connection, proxy fail, etc...), **encryption issues** (app doesn't decrypt the gobbledigook it receives), some applications may even refuse to launch if the **system clock** is wrong (I guess to prevent wrong date and time to make it into the database), **localization issues**?, **OS-version or edition**?, etc...

***Overall question***: are you launching as a valid user with the necessary AD group memberships and licenses on a machine that is current and up to date with the runtimes required and you have a working network connection with security software momentarily disabled for testing purposes?

---

Below is the original answer.

---

### Dependencies & Erroneous Configuration

A list of specific questions:

- ***Debugability***: Visual Studio?

  - Is this your own application so you have the **source code** available?
  - If so, does it run properly in **Visual Studio in debug mode**?
- ***Dependencies***: Have you tested for presence of basic, required runtime components / conditions?

  - Did you try to run the application in question on another computer first of all? A clean virtual machine, a test server, a test workstation an SOE machine? Are you testing using the same user credentials as you use on your dev-box?
  - Is the **target computer** the same **architecture** as your **developer machine**? What **CPU** are you targeting? Is there anything special about the problem, target computer? Does it have **weird policies**? Does it have **security software** blocking things? Does it **lack a common runtime component** that is installed on your development computer? (`.NET`, `VC++ runtime`, `VC runtime`, `java`, etc...).
  - If it works in Visual Studio, try to use the `modules view` to get an idea of what the project loads interactively: `Debug => Start Debugging`, then go `Debug => Windows => Modules`. It should show whatever was loaded to run your project interactively. Copy whatever is missing from your release folder in place when identified.
  - Have you run through a basic dependency check using tools such as [**Dependencies.exe**](http://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)? ([**direct link to release tab**](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases)).
  - There is also the aging and outdated [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which features a profiling feature (launch EXE and monitor dependencies). This is a C++ application as opposed to the mentioned `C# / C` application `Dependencies.exe`. It lacks handling of advanced features such as side-by-side assemblies and API-sets.
  - What does [**Fuslogvw.exe**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) report? (.NET assembly binding failures).
  - **[How do I determine the dependencies of a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application)** (just for reference).
- ***Configuration***: Could there be something wrong in your manifest file or some other settings file? Seems likely based on the log.

  - ***Paths***: Some relative path pointing to a folder in your source hierarchy not present on the normal box in release mode? **Hard-coded dev-box references** pointing to **missing resources** or **inaccessible network locations** on the release system?
  - ***Files***: Could there be **lacking resource files**? (images, dlls, etc...). Maybe it is just an image file or some sort of settings file that is missing altogether?
  - ***Process Monitoring***: These are the things a [**procmon.exe**](https://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe) session could help reveal. [**Primitive sample usage**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47792474/129130).

---

***Links*** (basically for safekeeping only):

- [C# Debug folder when copied to another location does not run the exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075972/c-sharp-debug-folder-when-copied-to-another-location-does-not-run-the-exe/48076373#48076373).
- [How do I determine the dependencies of a .NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227886/how-do-i-determine-the-dependencies-of-a-net-application)
- [After creating MSI Installer for WPF app in Visual Studio 2017, EXE does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901484/after-creating-msi-installer-for-wpf-app-in-visual-studio-2017-exe-does-nothing/47909700#47909700)
- [Registering a CPP dll into COM after installation using Wix Msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47746076/registering-a-cpp-dll-into-com-after-installation-using-wix-msi-installer/47755780#47755780)
- [How to find difference between the content of .exe and .msi (installer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25206469/how-to-find-difference-between-the-content-of-exe-and-msi-installer/25207723#25207723)
- [EXE file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651252/exe-file-is-not-working/48654444#48654444)
- [How do I fix a .NET windows application crashing at startup with Exception code: 0xE0434352?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244939/how-do-i-fix-a-net-windows-application-crashing-at-startup-with-exception-code)