# How to setup from VB 2008 success work in another computer?

Tags: vb.net, installation, windows-installer

I have created MSI of some project with VB net 2008, when I install in other computer is successfully, but when i try to run with double click the icon of this application is doesn't work. I try at windows 8 and 10 (x86, x64).
**someone may help my ??**

Comment: You should post, at least, a description of the actions your program performs when started. Also, add some logging capabilities, so you can inspect the log and see what happened. You might also find some clues in the System Event Log.

Comment: Is the correct version of the .NET framework installed? [There can be many reasons why an application won't launch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130). And you can skim [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49637913/129130) and throwing in [a list of dependency scanner tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130).

Comment: How it "doesn't work"?

Comment: not work...
I have  install net  framework, but is not work...

my computer using win 7 64 bit. I create project and create setup with it.
but when I try to install in other laptop  (win 8,10  64bit and 32bit) is success, but when I try to run, isn't work.  why??
what are elements that i must include when I create this setup?

Comment: Did you skim the list of suggestions available in the links provided above?

Comment: yes, i have do that, but not success...

Comment: Nobody can't help you until you'll provide all information about your issue.

Comment: I try to make some project in vb 2008, i using .net framework 3.5 and i using win 7 64 bit. 
I try to create setup of my project and I try and successes.
When I try to install this exe in win 10 and 8,  this process is success, but when I try to lunch the icon of my application is not work (is not run). 
I have try to install net framework 3.5 into win 10 and 8,but my application is not work.  whats this problem??

Comment: I have installed vb 2008 into computer target (win 10, 64 bit). my application is run good. My question what are elements must installing in computer target without installing vb 2008?