# Exe application won't execute on VM

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, windows-installer

I have a winforms application in visual studio that I used the wix installer extension to create a .msi for. When I run the installer it creates a folder for the app in my program files x86 folder with the .exe in it, and it runs just fine. However, when I run the .msi on my virtual machine it creates the folder and the .exe, but when I click on the .exe file the application doesn't work. I had some other people test the .msi on their own local computers and they had the same result. How can I fix this?

Comment: What runtime was missing? For the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Runtime Missing***: This indicates relatively strongly that you have a missing runtime of some sort. Ensure your runtime is installed, and in the required version too:

- ***Common***: **`VCRedist`**, **`.NET`**, **`.NET Core`**, **`Java`**, **`Direct X`**, etc...
- ***Specific***: **`Python`**, **`DBMS systems`** (**`PostgreSQL`**, **`MSSQL`**, etc...)
- ***Windows Components***: **`IIS`**, **`MSMQ - Message Queue`**, **`Powershell`**, etc...

---

***Missing Files***: There could also be missing files of other kinds - settings and various special cases. Here are some long debugging ideas lists:

- [Launch crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623588/windows-application-startup-error-exception-code-0xe0434352/49637913#49637913)
- [Launch fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512998/desktop-applicaton-not-opening-after-installation-in-client-system/53530377#53530377)
- [Scan for dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940598/129130)